# Read excel 'Formula Date cell' value in a specific format using Apache POI (excel has STRING FORMULA and INT FORMULA types)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

As part of Selenium automation, we need to read Excel (Apache POI and xls format file, HSSF) file which has STRING FORMULA and INTEGER FORMULA cells, Date values, and NUMERIC as well as STRING cells.

When tried the below approach facing an issue where the DateFormat needs to be updated to (yyyy-mm-dd) however it gives in the format of dd/mm/yy. Also the NUMERIC value is reading as STRING.

We have defined a method which returns String so that can read the value and pass it to JSON Payload.

```
public static String getData(String strSheetName, String strColumnIdentifier, int strRowIdentifier) throws IOException {

            String strAbsFilePath = getAbsolutePath("testdata" + File.separator + "New.xls");
            
            
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(strAbsFilePath);
    
        
            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
            fis.close();
            sheet = workbook.getSheet(strSheetName);
                            
            row = sheet.getRow(3);//// Making the object of excel row 
            
            DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
                
            
            int col_Num = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
                if (row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(strColumnIdentifier.trim()))
            
                    col_Num = i;
            }
            if (col_Num == -1)
                return "";
            row = sheet.getRow(strRowIdentifier);
            if (row == null)
                return "";
            
            cell = row.getCell(col_Num);
            formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
            
                            
            if(cell.getCellType() == CellType.FORMULA) {
                 PrintStream text = null;
                 switch(cell.getCachedFormulaResultType()) {
                  case STRING:
                     HSSFRichTextString str = cell.getRichStringCellValue();
                     if(str != null && str.length() > 0) {
                        
                        String cellValue = str.toString();
                        return cellValue;
                     }
                     break;
                  case NUMERIC:
                         HSSFCellStyle style = cell.getCellStyle();
                        
                         if(style == null) {
                            text.append( (char) cell.getNumericCellValue() );
                         } else {
                             
                            

    // cell.setCellType(CellType.NUMERIC);
                                 short df = workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd/mm/yyy");
//                               style.setDataFormat(df);
                                // cell.setCellStyle(style);
                                 DateFormat datetemp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyy");
                                 Date date = cell.getDateCellValue();
                                    String cellValue1 = datetemp.format(date);
                                    //style.setDataFormat(df);//If used this, all Numeric cell values are set to date format
                                 cellValue1=formatter.formatRawCellContents(
                                        cell.getNumericCellValue(),
                                        style.getDataFormat(),
                                        style.getDataFormatString()
                                        
                                  );
                                return cellValue1;
                             }
                             break;
                      case BOOLEAN:   
                          cell.getBooleanCellValue();
                          
                             
                     }
                     
                     }
                String cellStringValue = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                return cellStringValue;
    }
```

Output:

```
stringFieldValue value is: TestingExcelCell //Correctly getting as String
IntFieldValue value is: 11 //It is going as String in the Payload
ReportDate value is: 6/7/19 //This should come in the format of yyyy-mm-dd
```

Please suggest if needs to get the DateFormat in yyyy-mm-dd rather dd/mm/yy, and Integer value as Integer than String (11).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was to check if cell is in dateformat or not, then set the date format, after making below changes to condition, able to get the value in expected format.
Thanks for all the support.

```
  case NUMERIC:
                       //  HSSFCellStyle style = cell.getCellStyle();
                       CellStyle style = cell.getCellStyle();
                         if(style == null) {
                             cell.getNumericCellValue();
                            //text.append( (char) cell.getNumericCellValue() );
                         } else if(DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                             cell.setCellStyle(style);
                             SimpleDateFormat datetemp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                             //String formattedCell = datetemp.format(cell.getDateCellValue());

                             Date date = cell.getDateCellValue();
                                String formattedCell = datetemp.format(date);
                                return formattedCell;
                         }
```